# how to deal with join map futures

Tags: rust

I formerly was js developer.  i want to use rust implementing stuffs similar as below js code

```js
const urls = ["url1", "url2", "url3"];
const contents = await Promis.all(urls.map(async (url) => await getContent(url)));
```

rust code with compiling error

```rust
use futures::{join};
let all_futures = (1..4).collect::<Vec::<i32>>().iter().map(  |&i| async {
            client_rc.put(format!("k{}",i), format!("v{}",i)).await
}).collect::<Vec<_>>();
join!(all_futures).await;
```

the error is

```
`Vec<impl futures_util::Future<Output = [async output]>>` is not a future
the trait `futures_util::Future` is not implemented for `Vec<impl futures_util::Future<Output = [async output]>>`
Vec<impl futures_util::Future<Output = [async output]>> must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaitedrustcE0277
```

Answer (score 3):

The `join!` macro is for listing out several individual futures at compile time, like:

```
let a = async { ... };
let b = async { ... };
join!(a, b);
```

It doesn't understand how to wait for all of the futures in a collection.

Instead, use the [`join_all()`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.join_all.html) function, which can be used on any value implementing `IntoIterator<Item=impl Future>` to simultaneously await all of the produced futures.

```
join_all(all_futures).await;
```

Note that because this function accepts an iterator, you can skip the `.collect()` step altogether and give it the mapped iterator directly.  For example:

```
let futures = (0..4).map(|v| async move { v + 1 });
assert_eq!(
    join_all(futures).await,
    vec![1, 2, 3, 4]
);
```